# How to create a custom drop-down using react-select (like stackoverflow)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

Instead of a simple string using label options:

```
var options = [
  { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
  { value: 'two', label: 'Two' }
];
```

I want to use a custom component with complex data to populate each option. The selected tags could still be a `value, label` pair though.

A perfect example:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, react-select lets you pass in a custom menu component via the `menuRenderer` prop:

> Renders a custom menu with options; accepts the following named parameters: `menuRenderer({ focusedOption, focusOption, options, selectValue, valueArray })`

---

More info in [react-select's docs](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select).

Comment: Awesome, thanks! The only time I see menuRenderer mentioned is under "Efficiently rendering large lists with windowing", which doesn't give very many details. I assume the goal would be to append all other data to the objects holding `value,label` and then it could be utilized in the menuRenderer's prop that accepts those params. The prop would need to be a function that returns a react component correct? And that component would render a list of other components, one for each option.